# Check GA4 referrer information in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

If I want to aggregate referrers, is it safe to trust the value of "event_params.page_referrer"?

Initially, I was running a query like the one below.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_referrer') AS referrer,
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_location') AS landing
    COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM
    `bigquery-ga4-xxxxxxxx`
WHERE
    event_name = 'page_view'
AND
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_referrer') IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    referrer, landing
ORDER BY
    cnt DESC, landing
```

However, even if you have a value for "page_referrer", if you look at "traffic_source.source" you will find data like "(direct)" or "newsletter" etc...

I want to find out from which page it flowed to which page.
Is it okay to use the value of "page_referrer" as the axis?

If you have a detailed query example please let me know.